# Alternative to MSXML2 for VBA retrieving large HTTP requests, with access to readyState 3?

Tags: ajax, vba

**EDIT:** This question has changed as I have waited for an answer and done external research. I've rephrased the title, and the question is really that I'm looking for an alternative to MSXML2 (even if it means writing socket code).
The original body of the question is left here for reference and to help people in the future who are doing similar searches.

> In VBA, using MSXML2 object, is there a way to get access to the
>   streaming data while readyState = 3, as it comes in?
>
> I am using the `OnReadyStateChange` method, but I don't seem to have
>   access to `responseText` until readyState is 4. When readyState is 3,
>   there doesn't seem to be any data.
>
> Is there any way in VBA to have access to the HTTP streaming response
>   while it is coming in? Another method I could use in MSXML2, or a
>   better (free, distributable) object to use to make "AJAX" calls?
>
> More information: If I try to read `responseStream` (or
>   `responseText`), the error description is:
>
> `The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.`
>
> Second edit, more information:   This link basically says that this is
>   expected behavior in the `INTERACTIVE` (3) state:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753800(v=vs.85).aspx

**So I am definitely looking for the "is there any alternative?" answer.**

Comment: Does anyone have anything to say about WinHttp?

Comment: This is an old bit of code I wrote to reads chunks using the wininet API, its not asynchronous but it exposes a read buffer after every 512 bytes (I added a Debug.Print "READ " & lngTotalBytesRead to illustrate) - http://pastebin.com/6uMhkBUF - From what I can remember it worked ok but I've had to un-mangle it a bit.

Comment: Thank you Alex! I will play around with this code when I get a chance.

Comment: This looks great; I haven't fully explored it yet, but on the surface it looks like what I need. Please post your comment as an Answer so I can give you proper credit. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old bit of code I wrote to reads chunks using the WinInet API, its not asynchronous but it exposes a read buffer after every 512 bytes (I added a Debug.Print "READ " & lngTotalBytesRead to illustrate) - http://pastebin.com/6uMhkBUF

From what I can remember it worked ok but I've had to un-mangle it a bit.

- You will need to remove the calls to `App.` in `HTTPGetUAString` (This was VB6 originally) so just `HTTPGetUAString = "MyThing"` or the like.
- `If (lngContentLen = 0&) Then lngContentLen = (BUFF_LEN * DUMMY_BUFF_MULTIPLIER)` is a left-over; you can delete the line. (Subsequently if lngContentLen is zero the size is unknown in advance)

Comment: This is just about perfect! (I have to tweak it a little to use Basic Auth, and change the buffer size, and clean up some error-handling, etc, but in principle it is exactly what I need).

Comment: Alex K, please let me know if you have any problem with me using this code in my company's add-in (we do not charge any money for the add-in, just for the data it's accessing), and/or posting it as sample code to our website. (Basically do you have any open-source-license concerns?)  I will credit you appropriately if you want.

Comment: Nope its only a wee thing, it's yours to do with as you see fit.

Comment: Eventually I will link from here to my finished code (in the context of its actual use) for future generations.  I am modifying it in bits and pieces, like: removing the "full sized buffer" and *only* processing the chunks, increasing the incremental buffer size from 512 bytes to 65000-ish, judicious additions of DoEvents, etc.  I am trying to beat this into submission so it no longer goes into "(Not Responding)" state and getting very close. You got me 80% of the way there, thanks again Alex!