# Loop through a full XML document

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, recursion

I'm looking for a way to loop through all the nodes of my XML document.

**XML file sample**

```xml
<root>
    <llnode created="2005-05-24T15:26:24" createdby="42912153" createdbyname="" description="" id="107810306" modified="2008-06-05T16:07:44" name="" objname="" objtype="0" ownedby="42912153" ownedbyname="" parentid="107810295" size="4">
        <Nickname domain=""/>
        <MajorMinorContainer>false</MajorMinorContainer>
        <llnode created="2005-05-06T12:54:03" createdby="42912153" createdbyname="" description="" id="107815681" modified="2006-12-04T14:39:51" name="" objname="" objtype="0" ownedby="42912153" ownedbyname="" parentid="107810306" size="0">
            <Nickname domain=""/>
            <MajorMinorContainer>false</MajorMinorContainer>
        </llnode>
        <llnode created="2005-05-06T12:54:31" createdby="42912153" createdbyname="" description="" id="107815683" modified="2006-12-04T14:39:53" name="" objname="" objtype="0" ownedby="42912153" ownedbyname="" parentid="107810306" size="0">
            <Nickname domain=""/>
            <MajorMinorContainer>false</MajorMinorContainer>
        </llnode>
    </llnode>
    <llnode created="2005-05-24T15:26:24" createdby="42912153" createdbyname="" description="" id="107810306" modified="2008-06-05T16:07:44" name="" objname="" objtype="0" ownedby="42912153" ownedbyname="" parentid="107810295" size="4">
        <Nickname domain=""/>
        <MajorMinorContainer>false</MajorMinorContainer>
        <llnode created="2005-05-06T12:54:03" createdby="42912153" createdbyname="" description="" id="107815681" modified="2006-12-04T14:39:51" name="" objname="" objtype="0" ownedby="42912153" ownedbyname="" parentid="107810306" size="0">
            <Nickname domain=""/>
            <MajorMinorContainer>false</MajorMinorContainer>
        </llnode>
        <llnode created="2005-05-06T12:54:31" createdby="42912153" createdbyname="" description="" id="107815683" modified="2006-12-04T14:39:53" name="" objname="" objtype="0" ownedby="42912153" ownedbyname="" parentid="107810306" size="0">
            <Nickname domain=""/>
            <MajorMinorContainer>false</MajorMinorContainer>
        </llnode>
    </llnode>
</root>
```

The document always has the same structure. Each *llnode* represents a folder. This can go really deep (for the purpose of the above example, the scope is only 2, but it can go up to 10).

How can I loop through all the records? I don't want to put a loop into a loop and then another loop and do this like 20 times to be sure to handle every node. Is there a way to just do a loop of loops?

Below is what I got so far, only working for the actual XML document (scope=2), would need to add as much loops as the scope increases (it shouldn't go over scope=10)

**Original VBA** (from original question)

```vb
xmlExportDoc = "myXmlDoc.xml"

Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmlDoc.Load (xmlExportDoc)

Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//llnode")

For Each Node In xmlNodeList
   MsgBox "Listing the EXISTING nodes"
   MsgBox Node.nodeName & " " & Node.NodeValue & " " & Node.NodeType

   If Node.HasChildNodes() Then
      MsgBox Node.nodeName & "has child nodes"
      Set xmlNodeList2 = Node.ChildNodes

      For Each Node2 In oNodeList2
          MsgBox Node2.nodeName & " " & Node2.NodeValue & " " & Node2.NodeType

          If Node2.HasChildNodes() Then
             MsgBox Node2.nodeName & "has child nodes"
          End If
      Next
   End If
Next
```

**UPDATED VBA**

```vb
Private Function xmlParse(n As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode)
    Dim n2 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    MsgBox n.nodeName & " " & n.NodeValue & " " & n.NodeType

    If n.HasChildNodes() Then
        MsgBox n.nodeName & " has child nodes"

        For Each n2 In n.ChildNodes
            xmlParse (n2)
        Next

        MsgBox "Done listing child nodes for " & n.nodeName
    End If
End Function
```

And the code of the event:

```vb
    Dim xmlExportDoc As String
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, xmlNodeList2
    Dim Node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    xmlExportDoc = "http://myserver.com/myDoc.xml"

    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load (xmlExportDoc)

    Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//llnode")

    For Each Node In xmlNodeList
        Call xmlParse(Node)
    Next
```

This still don't work, got an error when doing the recursive `xmlParse()` call because `MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode.ChildNodes` doesn't seem to be a `MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode` type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you need here is a recursive function. I don't really know VBA syntax so forgive the pseudocode, but you should be able to do something like this:

```vb
Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/*/llnode")
For Each node in xmlNodeList
    ListNodes(node)
Next

Function ListNodes(n As Node) 
     MsgBox n.nodeName & " " & n.NodeValue & " " & n.NodeType
     If n.HasChildNodes() Then
        MsgBox n.nodeName & "has child nodes"
        For Each n2 in n.ChildNodes
           ListNodes(n2)
        Next
        MsgBox "Done listing child nodes for " & n.nodeName
     End If   
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about recursivity before. Thank you very much, I will give this a try. Any reason to change //llnode for /*/node?

Comment: Yes, `/*/llnode` selects the top-level `llnodes`. `//llnode` selects all `llnodes` in the document at all depths in one single set.

Comment: Oops, I'm not really familial with XML, I guess /llnode and */llnode also produces different results. In fact, the <root> in my above example is also a <llnode>.

Comment: I get an automation error telling me that the data aren't yet available (when doing the `For Each node in xmlNodeList`).

Comment: It works if I wait 10 seconds. Wow, what's going on lol, is it because the `.SelectNodes()` is somehow done in background?

Comment: Are you retrieving the XML file from the internet?  It seems that perhaps the xmlDoc.Load() method is asynchronous. This SO question seems to be referring to a similar issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13744301/1945651)

Comment: Yes it's from Internet. Thanks for pointing that out, more on this Monday.

Comment: Just added `xmlDoc.async = False` and now it waits for the XML doc to be fully loaded.

Comment: @JLRishes just updated my original post with part of your code but it's still don't work, I get an error when trying a recursive call to xmlParse because the MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode object's ChildNodes doesn't seem to be of the same type.

Comment: Could you try changing all occurrences the following so that their first letter is lowercase: `NodeValue`, `ChildNodes`, `HasChildNodes()` [Here] is the documentation on the members of `MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode`.

Comment: I think you forgot to put the link. I found an alternative that seems to work, I will post it below, no recursivity but it still looks like it goes as deep as needed. Tell me what you think about it.

Comment: Yes, I did forget the link. [Here it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms761386(v=vs.85).aspx). As you can see, all of the interface's members start with lowercase. According to the documentation, `childNodes` should be na IXMLDOMNodeList, just like the one you're using in your code.

Comment: Well, Microsoft Visual Basic editor (v6.3) automatically puts back the uppercase letter if I try to remove it. I'm using Microsoft XML v6.0 as reference.

Comment: The code from my answer does work but I think it just searches for every node whatever level it is. Because it's just to add all the informations into a database and that parent folder's id are also in the attributes, it should get the job done.

Comment: My solution working. +1 for yours too and I will accept it also, thanks for your help. Recursivity is the answer to my original question, I just didn't realize at that time that I just don't care about hierarchy of the nodes and that I just want to loop through all nodes whatever level it is.

Comment: Great.  Thanks, and I hope you find the occasion to recursively loop through XML sometime in the future. :)

Comment: I'm late for this chat but I'm working on the same issue: I have JLRishe's solution but I cannot call `ListNodes(node)`. I always get **RuntimeError 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"**. Does anyone know why and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I come with so far:

```vb
xmlExportDoc = "http://www.mysite.com/myDoc.xml"

Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim myNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xmldoc.async = False
xmldoc.Load (xmlExportDoc)
Set xmlNodeList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("*")
On Error Resume Next
For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
    For Each myNode In xmlNode.ChildNodes
        'Debug.Print xmlNode.Attributes(0).Text
    Next myNode
Next xmlNode
Set xmldoc = Nothing
```

It works if the hierarchy isn't important, because this script just loops through the nodes whatever level it is. If hierarchy is important, look at JLRishe's answer.